# How to get notification as a popup on home/lockscreen in android?

Tags: java, android

![enter image description here][1]I want to get notification in popup/alertDialog in my application (like whatsapp). 
Also, I want to take multiple kinds of input from the user (Checkbox, RadioButtons, EditText, etc) as shown in the image @ http://www.android-hilfe.de/attachments/whatsapp/92660d1337810736-whatsapp-popup-bei-gesperrtem-bildschirm-shot_000006.png

Comment: http://www.android-hilfe.de/attachments/whatsapp/92660d1337810736-whatsapp-popup-bei-gesperrtem-bildschirm-shot_000006.png

Answer (score 0):

Use WindowManager for adding views:

```
    WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);

    View view = new LinearLayout(this);

    final WindowManager.LayoutParams params = ...;

    windowManager.addView(view, params);
```